# Update to table causing page level lock on child table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a live environment we have a table we are trying to very regularly run updates on, for example lets call this Employee. However, when we update this table we are getting a page level lock on a child table, for example let's call this EmployeeAddress. This is leading to transaction deadlocks/blocked processes in the db.

The code is a very simple update, similar to this: `update Employee set fieldA = A, fieldB = B ... WHERE employeeId = x`, which then sometimes causes a page level lock on EmployeeAddress, deadlocking other processes.

My question: has anyone seen similar deadlocks/page level locks? I'm pretty sure removing the fk constraint on EmployeeId in the EmployeeAddress table would fix the issue, but surely SQL Server should be able to handle this fk constraint without having these deadlock issues?

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to add, one possible suggestion we had was to amend the fill factor settings to the child table, is this a sound option?

Comment: Add the deadlock trace to your question.

Comment: On its face, it does sound like an issue with the FK between the two tables. Though if FK is on EmployeeID and you're not updating that, it seems weird to me that the child table would need to be involved at all.

Comment: Does the child table have an index on the foreign key (as the first column in the index)? Please add the deadlock graph, relevant table and index definitions, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Fill factor will not make any difference

Comment: I would think the problem is an update to the EmployeeAddress table - and not the update to the Employee table.  An update on EmployeeAddress may need a lock on the Employee table to validate the EmployeeID - but without seeing the deadlock graph this is just a guess.